# manifest for ignores no-caching

Tags: html, cache-manifest

I changed my HTML-code to HTML5. To control the caching, I defined the following manifest.appcache

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#2015-03-23 17-25

CACHE:

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
```

I just have an index.php which generates my HTML-code. Different content will be displayed acording to get-parameters. But although I use `NETWORK: *` for some reasons, browsers just only display the cached files. Even when I change the comment of the manifest file.
I also tried to delete the appcache files in chrome by chrome://appcache-internals/, but this works only once and afterwards, cached files are displayed again.
I additionally added the obsolete meta-tags, but this does help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="http://killmore-patamon.esy.es/manifest.appcache">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
</head>
<bod>

...

</body>
</html>
```